# How to handle both buttons click (left+right at the same time) with JS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a Minesweeper game using jQuery, I'm successfully handling left and right clicks with event.which, but is it possible to detect a click with the left and right buttons at the same time?

Comment: Do you really mean "at the same time"? I think that you want to know "how can I detect that one mouse button gets pressed before the other one went up?"

Comment: You're right, I want to know when the second button is pressed before the release of the first one, sorry.

Comment: For elegant implementation, look into [jQuery special events](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/03/26/special-events).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i doubt that you will ever get both at the same time, once will come first, even if by a few ms.

set a flag when either one is set and check for that flag in the other

Comment: Hmh... so playing with mousedown and mouseup... Thanks, I'll try it :)